# How to send SMS in response to CloudWatch alarm after 2023 origination number changes

Tags: amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-sns

Hopefully I'm missing a simple way to do this.  I have a CloudWatch alarm set up for an EC2 instance.  The alarm publishes to an SNS topic, which in turn triggers an SMS to my personal phone number.  This is literally the only thing we want to use SMS for in AWS, for sending alarm notifications.

However, after the changes to phone number acquisition this year, in order to get a 10DLC number I now have to set up a brand registration and campaign registration.  I get why they added this, but it doesn't apply to what I'm trying to do.  I don't want to set up opt-in, opt-out processes.  Is there a way around this?  I set up a registration simply explaining how we're trying to use SMS, and it was rejected.

Comment: I don't there is a work around. Setting up an email notification to a dedicated email id is probably the easiest way to get a notification. You can also setup notification from an phone app like [nfty](https://github.com/binwiederhier/ntfy) or setup some other forwarding from a Raspberry etc.